# Terraform : Invalid provider configuration for third-party providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I am facing issue to add third-party terraform provider, this is link I am following [wiz](https://docs.wiz.io/wiz-docs/docs/auto-connect-clusters). I added wiz provider in main.tf and root module as well. I am not sure what am I missing here.
I have following code structure :

```
/root
/infra-module
    --> wiz-module
        - main.tf
            //required_providers{//aws //wiz}
        - providers.tf
        - data.tf
        - variables.tf
/terraform-deplyment
        - main.tf
        - providers.tf
            //required_providers{//wiz}
            //provider "wiz" {//clientid and secret}
        - data.tf
            //aws-secret-manager //secret
        - variables.tf
            //clientid
        - terraform.tfvars
```

Error facing is,
[image]

Providers are added in "terraform-deployment" as follows,

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
      configuration_aliases = [ aws , aws.management]
    }
    wiz = {
      source  = "tf.app.wiz.io/wizsec/wiz"
    }    
  }
}
provider "wiz" {
    client_id = var.wiz_clientid
    secret = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.get_wiz_secert.id
    alias = //tried adding alias
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i dont think you are able to use the secret like that as the providers get downloaded beforehand , hence you cannot fetch the secret from secret manager

see here: https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration

Comment: Thank you @Darren for your input !! You are right, I was calling it in providers.tf where it cannot fetch values. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For above issue, it was found that we must make sure where are we calling values like for pulling secrets from AWS in terraform. I was using it in providers.tf and so it was not getting any relevant values.

Terraform Reference Document for above issue : https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).